# CSS background image will not show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

For the life of me, I cannot get a simple background image to show up using CSS. I have a dead simple HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>My Website</title>
<LINK href="./css/styles.css" rel=StyleSheet  type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<p>foo</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And the following CSS page:

```
body {
    background:url('./images/myBackground.jpg');
}
```

Yet the image never shows. I've Googled this and many people seem to have encountered this same problem, but none of the solutions have worked. I've tried every combination of CSS syntax I can think of (background, background-image, no quotes, single quotes, double quotes, slash, no slash, etc.) -- no luck. I've tried putting the image in the same directory as the HTML page -- no luck. I've tried making a square div and setting its background to this image -- no luck. I've tried setting a fixed height and width -- no luck.

There's no spelling errors and I know there's nothing wrong with the image because it works using an inline image tag in the HTML. The HTML and CSS page are linked because I can do something like

```
p {
    color: blue;
}
```

and that works. Am I missing something incredibly obvious here? I can do it inline, but I'd really prefer to use CSS and now I just want to do it out of stubbornness and principal.

Comment: Maybe `./images/myBackground.png` or whatever your file name extension is?

Comment: My bad, I actually do have the file extension in there

Comment: Please modify your post to reflect that.

Comment: try narrowing down the issue by adding a temporary style to your html like this http://jsfiddle.net/mnc4qn66/  if the image shows up then the problem is with adding your style to the page, if it doesn't work then the problem is with your background file-path

Comment: use FireBug to inspect the image, and make sur the css file is loaded

Comment: also, if you're using visual studio or deamweaver you can drag and drop your image from the folder in your file nav onto your screen and you'll get the real path to the file.

Comment: Dan, I tried adding the temporary style and that worked. Turns out the problem was that it was trying to load the image from ./css/images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put an extra "." in front of the url.

You are now linking to /css/images/mybackground.

If you put an extra "." in front of it, like ../images/myBackground
(and add the extension like mentioned)

It should work. (At least it does in my reproduction of your situation.)

Comment: this sounds about right actually, for some reason I accepted the single dot as intentional.

Comment: I just pulled up the console, and this is what's happening. There was a big, red "Failed to load resource" message right there...

Comment: I used your code exactly as stated by you. (with the extension). The console gave me the exact same error as you. But when i changed it to background-image: url("../images/myBackground.jpg"); it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the extension .png, .jpg, .gif etc

```
   background:url('../images/myBackground.png');

 background:url('../images/myBackground.jpg');
```

Comment: Note that the OP stated in the comments that he actually did have the file extension in there.